# MATLAB FDAtool export

Tags: matlab

I designed a highpass FIR filter whic when exported as MATLAB code gave me the following:

```
function Hd = aaa
%AAA Returns a discrete-time filter object.

% MATLAB Code
% Generated by MATLAB(R) 8.3 and the Signal Processing Toolbox 6.21.
% Generated on: 13-May-2015 09:14:52

% Equiripple Highpass filter designed using the FIRPM function.

% All frequency values are normalized to 1.

Fstop = 0.1;             % Stopband Frequency
Fpass = 0.18;            % Passband Frequency
Dstop = 0.01;            % Stopband Attenuation
Dpass = 0.057501127785;  % Passband Ripple
dens  = 20;              % Density Factor

% Calculate the order from the parameters using FIRPMORD.
[N, Fo, Ao, W] = firpmord([Fstop, Fpass], [0 1], [Dstop, Dpass]);

% Calculate the coefficients using the FIRPM function.
b  = firpm(N, Fo, Ao, W, {dens});
Hd = dfilt.dffir(b);

% [EOF]
```

I also generated a sine wave using MATLAB code.

How can I pass this sine wave into the filter to analyze the output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB filter code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30201521/matlab-filter-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`filter`](http://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/filter.html) function applies a filter to an input vector. It is overloaded to allow various filter types as input - e.g. also discrete-time filter objects, such as the one you designed. 
The syntax is:

```
y = filter(Hd,x);
```

where `Hd` is the discrete-time filter object you designed in the function (PS: think about giving the function a more meaningful name than `aaa`), and `x` is the input signal, e.g. your sine wave. The output of the filter is then `y`.